# PHP Warning: oci_fetch_all(): ORA-01722: invalid number in ORACLE PIVOT

Tags: php, oracle, pivot

So, I have a query that when I execute it with the client sql developer I get results.
The query:

```
 select * from
    (
      select art_no, descr, store_no, stock
      from (
          select * from gr_rep.mmart_analysis@ss001 where disp_info in  ( '0','4' )
          union all 
          select * from gr_rep.mmart_analysis@ss002 where disp_info in  ( '0','4' ) 
          union all 
          select * from gr_rep.mmart_analysis@ss003 where disp_info in  ( '0','4' )
          union all 
          select * from gr_rep.mmart_analysis@ss004 where disp_info in  ( '0','4' )
          union all 
          select * from gr_rep.mmart_analysis@ss005 where disp_info in  ( '0','4' )
          union all 
          select * from gr_rep.mmart_analysis@ss006 where disp_info in  ( '0','4' )
          union all 
          select * from gr_rep.mmart_analysis@ss007 where disp_info in  ( '0','4' )
          union all 
          select * from gr_rep.mmart_analysis@ss008 where disp_info in  ( '0','4' )
          union all 
          select * from gr_rep.mmart_analysis@ss009 where disp_info in  ( '0','4' )
          union all 
          select * from gr_rep.mmart_analysis@ss010 where disp_info in  ( '0','4' )
          union all 
          select * from gr_rep.mmart_analysis@ss011 where disp_info in  ( '0','4' )
      ) x
    )
    pivot
    (
      sum(stock)
      for store_no in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
    )
order by art_no desc
```

The results:
[image]

When I run it with php like `$res = oci_execute($p,OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);` in line with the `$n = oci_fetch_all ($p, $res, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);` I get: `[04-Feb-2016 17:15:35 Europe/Athens] PHP Warning:  oci_fetch_all(): ORA-01722: invalid number` 

Can someone give a helping hand?

Comment: These errors mostly boil down to different NLS settings in SQL Developer vs PHP. Examine the results from `select * from nls_session_parameters;` in both environments, resolve any differences, and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Yo! Martin you are right! I just made ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.'; and that's it! Thanx mate!